# find element by xpath with contains(node()) AND contains(@attribute)

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to locate an element by checking innerHTML (property node()) and some attribute (e.g. @class).
Both methods works separately but I can't combine them with "and"

HTML part:

```
<tr class="tableRow1">
  <td nowrap="" class="ct">
    <input type="CheckBox" name="RowKey" tabindex="17" value="15635">
    <img src="/tm/images/1pixel.gif" style="height:9px;width:9px;border:0" name="RowIndicator">
  </td>
  <td class="lt" title="ID">XXXXX</td><nobr>0021234567</nobr><td class="rt">1.00</td>
</tr>
```

So I need to locate this node of *class="tableRow1"* (from many others) by catching this part:

```
<nobr>002123456</nobr>.
```

This two works (but catching several elements):

```
.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[contains(node(), "0021234567")]')
.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[contains(@class, "Row")]')
```

This one doesn't:

```
.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[contains(node(),"0021234567") and contains(@class,"Row")]')
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @DebanjanB ok, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
descendant::*[contains(node(), "0021234567")]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class, "Row")][1]
```

or in a complete instruction

```
.find_element_by_xpath('descendant::*[contains(node(), "0021234567")]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class, "Row")][1]')
```

This instruction selects the first `tr` ancestor - which has a `class` attribute which contains the value `Row` - of a (global) `node()` which contains the value `0021234567`.

Comment: well, it seems to work, but now I need to limit <tr> element by several nested elements. so instead of descendant/ancestor combination I've finally found how to add all the nested elements as a limiting option (added details to the comment below)

Answer (score 1):

Your two XPath selectors are selecting different nodes.

The node that contains the string is a descendant of the `<tr>` node with the class name. That is why when you are putting both conditions for one node it doesn't find any matching node.

Try this:

```
.find_element_by_xpath('//[contains(node(), "0021234567")]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class), "Row"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

To locate the `<tr>` nodes which contains the child `<nobr>` nodes you can use the following solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//nobr//ancestor::tr[contains(@class, 'Row')]")
```

**Note**: It is assumed that the `innerText` within the `<nobr>` is a variable else the `innerText` can be included within the *XPath expression* as well.

Comment: well, it seems to work, but now I need to limit <tr> element by several nested elements. so instead of descendant/ancestor combination I've finally found how to add all the nested elements as a limiting option (updated my question)

Answer (score 1):

> So I need to locate this node of *class="tableRow1"* (from many
>   others) by catching this part:
>
> ```
> <nobr>002123456</nobr>
> ```

The XPath expression should be:

```
//tr[@class='tableRow1'][.//nobr='002123456']
```

That is the basic. Then you could adjust that to your situation.

- Example 1 *(many posible classes tokens)*:

  `//tr[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' tableRow1 ')][.//nobr='002123456']`
- Example 2 *(posible white space in `nobr`)*:

  `//tr[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' tableRow1 ')]
       [.//nobr[normalize-space()='002123456']]`
- Example 3 *(class token starts with `'tableRow'`)*:

  `//tr[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' tableRow')]
       [.//nobr[normalize-space()='002123456']]`

Comment: well, it points me to the option of adding ".//" to find some nested element in the required parent node and join it with other needed limitations. so i've ended up with the following request (there's now two limiting elements inside, which becomes needed by updated business-logic behind): `"//tr[.//nobr[contains(text(), '021234566')] and .//td[contains(text(), 'OPTION')] and contains(@class,'Row')]"`. Which means: find <tr> with: nested <nobr> with substring "021234566", nested <td> with substring "OPTION" and class attribute with substring "Row"

Comment: @laooglee Whenever you work with mixed content (text and markup) don't use the text nodes (like in `text()` node test) because text might be wrapped by inline markup. Use string value instead like in `//tr[.//nobr[contains(., '021234566')] and .//td[contains(., 'OPTION')] and contains(@class,'Row')]`